# how can i exclude a null record in microsoft sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wanted to not to display a null record in SQL server management studio

**example :**

```
select * from customer where customerid is not null
```

but i am getting the null records as well under the column customerid .

Comment: Please show some example output. It's not clear whether the "null records" you refer to actually have a null in the customerid column (unlikely) or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should have removed all records where the `customer` is `NULL`.  If you are still seeing records which appear to be `NULL`, then I speculate that there is actually some sort of data there, e.g. whitespace.  For example, if there were spaces in those unexpected records, the following query would find them:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE TRIM(customer) = '';
```

Try having a close look at some of these records and see if you find any data for the `customerid`.